# PyATE library - Exception has occurred: FileNotFoundError

Tags: python, nlp

I just starting my journey in python, and now I am interested in doing NLP. I'm currently trying to create a term extracting model using PyATE (automated term extraction). I've followed the installation guide, but I seem to be missing something. Can you guys help?

I have tried googling other sources, but it seems that this library has less public uses than I thought[my attempt in trying the library](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wj9RN.png)